# How to display 3 lists together using Python 3 + django2?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a list as follow:

```
item1, [subitems] 
item2, [subitems]
 ... 
itemN, [subitems]
```

For instance, item1 .. itemN might be a list of classes, and [subitems] contains a list of students that attend each class. A student might attend more than 1 class.

Each class and student has a description (in a string variable).

I want to create a (static) table that contains two columns. The first column is the list of classes.

When I click to one element in the first column, the second column will display the list of students attend this class. Also, the description of the class will be displayed.

If I click to a student, the cell will expand and display the description of the student.

Sorry if the description is not so clear. The idea is as the image following:

The list and description are stored in TXT files, not database.

[image]

Comment: So, exactly where are you stuck? What code do you have so far?

Comment: I stuck at the beginning (I am very new with django). Probably you can give me some keywords to implement the idea?

Comment: First Start with :  1) write class for student , 2) write class for classroom, 3) add student to classroom , after that you can access each class and each student, try to add different variables(characteristics - student_name, classroom_name....) and methods(get_self_name()...) for same

Comment: They are done already. I just don't know what kinds of view element should be used to display the interactive table?

Comment: how you are planning to show all students for a class in 2nd column (as you specified) try to show data in some popup or new html when click on class(1st column), Try to call ajax function when particular class(1st column) is clicked to get student data